# problem with accesing multiple values using django

Tags: python, django

I am new to python and I am using django for student database application .
Student database application must show id, firstname,lastname,subjectnames,marks.
Single student is having multiple subjects and their marks.
I am getting problem with accessing multiple values that student is having multiple subjects and marks.

models.py

```
class Person(models.Model):
    firstname=models.CharField(max_length=50)
    lastname=models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return (self.firstname,self.lastname)


class Marksheet(models.Model):
    subname=models.CharField(max_length=50)
    marks=models.IntegerField(max_length=10)
    person=models.ForeignKey(Person)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.subname
```

views.py

```
def add_page(request,page_name): # function for creating  the new records
    p1=None
    p2=None
    if request.method=='POST':
        p1=Person(firstname=request.POST['firstname'],lastname=request.POST['lastname'])
        p1.save()
        p2=Marksheet(subname=request.POST.getlist('subnames'),person=Person(person_id))
        p2.save()
    return render_to_response("add.html",{"page_name":page_name})
```

creating a records I am using form in html which is shown below....

Templates 
add.html

```
<form method="post" action="/newdcl/{{page_name}}/add/" > {% csrf_token %}
    First name:  <input type="text" name="firstname" /> <br />
    Last name:  <input type="text" name="lastname" /> <br /> 
    Operating System  <input value="os" name="subnames" type="checkbox"><br />
    System Programming <input value="sp" name="subnames" type="checkbox"> <br />
    Maths <input value="maths" name="subnames" type="checkbox"> <br />        
    <input type="submit" value="save" >
</form>
```

Can anyone help me in this????

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/#forms

Comment: yes, please look at Django forms as DR linked above. And then use the `.is_valid` method described in saving the form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem seems to lie in your how you try to create Marksheet, you can't assign a list of values to one field like that.
Using your currently formless, scary, no-validation, setup... you can do something like this-

```
p1=Person(firstname=request.POST['firstname'], 
          lastname=request.POST['lastname'])
p1.save()
for subname in request.POST.getlist('subnames'):
    new = MarkSheet(subname=subname, person=p1) 
        #no data for marks, must define it to be able to be blank/null
    new.save()
```

You will need to add `blank=True, null=True` to you marks field in your models.py if you intend to not have any initial mark.

Please look at [Making Queries](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/db/queries/) and [Forms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/forms/)

Comment: Thank you ..it is very useful...but how can i get marks from user for each of subject.How can i display in template?

Comment: in your view get the specific user `p = Person.objects.get(firstname='Bob', lastname='Smith')` then query the Marksheet for objects with that user `marks_list = Marksheet.objects.filter(person=p)` pass that queryset to your template in your context_dictionary, then iterate over that list of objects in your view `{% for mark in marks_list %} <p>Subject: {{ mark.subname }} Marks: {{ mark.marks }}</p>{% endfor %}`

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion it should be done by using many-to-many relation in Person, and form should be defined as a form class, because you don't have any validation in your form, and you are writing some html, which could be generated by putting one line of code in template. I would do it like this:

models.py

```
class Marksheet(models.Model):
    subname=models.CharField(max_length=50)
    marks=models.IntegerField(max_length=10)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.subname

class Person(models.Model):
    firstname=models.CharField(max_length=50)
    lastname=models.CharField(max_length=50)
    marksheets = models.ManyToManyField(Marksheet)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return (self.firstname,self.lastname)
```

forms.py
    from models import Person

```
class PersonForm(ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(PersonForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        # by default m2m relation is rendered with SelectMultiple widget -
        # - below line is changing it to checkbox list
        self.fields['marksheets'].widget = forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple()
    class Meta:
        model = Person
```

views.py

```
#inside your view function
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = PersonForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()

# pass form to template in render_to_response
```

add.html

```
<form method="post" action="/newdcl/{{page_name}}/add/" > {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form }}
    <input type="submit" value="save" >
</form>
```

Comment: No, widgets can be used only in forms. Why would you do that? Creating form from a model is simple and effortless, and doesn't require writing tones of code.